# Ruby Sinatra Routes Not Being Recognized

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm having some issues with Sinatra not recognizing my routes (all other routes work fine, it is just this specific set of 4 routes). The layout is: in my `views`, the user clicks on a filter button which corresponds to the route of `/all` `/inactive` `/active` or `/expired`, and should filter out based on this selection.

Here is the `index.haml` filters:

```
%form{method: 'GET', action: "/showings/all"}
      %input#all.btn.btn-md.btn-secondary{type: 'submit', value: 'All'}
%form{method: 'GET', action: "/showings/active"}
      %input#active.btn.btn-md.btn-secondary{type: 'submit', value: 'Active'}
%form{method: 'GET', action: "/showings/inactive"}
      %input#inactive.btn.btn-md.btn-secondary{type: 'submit', value: 'Inactive'}
%form{method: 'GET', action: "/showings/expired"}
      %input#expired.btn.btn-md.btn-secondary{type: 'submit', value: 'Expired'}
%form{method: 'DELETE', action: "/showings/delete", style: "padding-left: 45%"}
      %input#delete.btn.btn-md.btn-danger{type: 'submit', value: 'Delete Expired Hosted Screenings'}
```

However, in my `showings_routes.rb` file in my `controllers` folder, I tried these route but they never get registered (I've tried restarting the web app):

```
get '/all' do
    p "ALL ROUTES"
    haml :'showings/index'
  end

  get '/active' do
    p "ACTIVE ROUTES"
    haml :'showings/index'
  end

  get '/inactive' do
    p "INACTIVE ROUTES"
    haml :'showings/index'
  end

  get '/expired' do
    p "EXPIRED ROUTES"
    haml :'showings/index'
  end

  delete '/delete' do
    p "DELETE ROUTES"
    redirect '/showings'
  end
```

I'm planning on adding the filter logic later, the routes are just not being recognized when I click one of the buttons or navigate to `localhost:3000/showings/all`. I'm just confused because this is a built web app, so all the other routes in the `showings_routes.rb` file work fine (like `/create` `/submit` etc.)

Is there a thing that I'm missing when I'm handling my routes here in my application?

Comment: maybe `get '/showings/all`

Comment: No such luck sadly, still is not a valid route.